# how to know if thread execution is terminated?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a thread:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //...
   Thread th = new Thread(DoWork);
   th.Start(); 
}
```

what's the best way to know if thread is terminated?
I'm looking for an example code how do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few simple things you can do.

You could use `Thread.Join` to see if the thread has ended.

```
var thread = new Thread(SomeMethod);
thread.Start();
while (!thread.Join(0)) // nonblocking
{
  // Do something else while the thread is still going.
}
```

And of course if you do not specify a timeout parameter then the calling thread will block until the worker thread ends.

You could also invoke a delegate or event at the end of entry point method.

```
// This delegate will get executed upon completion of the thread.
Action finished = () => { Console.WriteLine("Finished"); };

var thread = new Thread(
  () =>
  {
    try
    {
      // Do a bunch of stuff here.
    }
    finally
    {
      finished();
    }
  });
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Usually the callback methods will try to do a cross-thread operation like 
updating the UI specifying that the process is completed. If your UI controls doesn't support cross-thread operation you will get a InvalidOperationException saying the control is accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on, which can be avoided by invoking the callback method like this

`this.Invoke(finished);`

Answer (score 5):

thread State

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to wait until the thread is finished you can use.

```
th.Join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 
`Thread.join()` as harlam said.
chech this link for more clearness:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx

> Use this method to ensure a thread has terminated. The caller will
>   block indefinitely if the thread does not terminate. If the thread has
>   already terminated when Join is called, the method returns
>   immediately.